# Adding onSelectChanged event to a dynamically created calendars

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

In my .ascx user control I have some ImageButton elements and when these are clicked they create dynamically and then show Calendar Element adding it to a PlaceHolder. I have three of them and the function will generate an ID for each calendar created from the ID of the ImageButton that is clicked. I am trying to dynamically add a SelectionChanged event for each calendar created.

I declared an empty object calendar as a global variable at the beginning of the class. I instantiate a new Calendar object onPageLoad, at the click event I add the ID, event and add it to the placeholder.

The SelectChange event does not seem to work though. What is missing?

`public partial class admin_CaptureDate : System.Web.UI.UserControl`
`{`
    `protected Calendar DateCalendar;`

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    DateCalendar = new Calendar();
    DateCalendar.ID = "DateCalendar";
    DateCalendar.Width = 176;
    DateCalendar.SelectionChanged += Calendar_SelChanged;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void ShowCalendar_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) 
{
    ImageButton btnSender = (ImageButton)sender;
    string Prefix = btnSender.ID.Substring(14);
    Trace.Write("this is prefix " + Prefix);
    this.FindControl(Prefix + "PlaceHolder").Controls.Add(DateCalendar);
}
protected void Calendar_SelChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Calendar SelectedCalendar = (Calendar)sender;
    string SelectedDate = SelectedCalendar.SelectedDate.ToLongDateString();
    Trace.Write("this is the selected date" + SelectedDate);
}
```

`}`

Still doesn't work, the event is not attached to the calendar, what is still missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the calendar, add it to the page's control-colection and add the event handler in `Page_Init`. The events are too late.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    DateCalendar = new Calendar();
    DateCalendar.SelectionChanged += Calendar_SelChanged;
}
```

They also always have to get the same ID as before. But it seems that you change the ID according to the `Button.ID` here:

```
string Prefix = btnSender.ID.Substring(14);
DateCalendar.ID = Prefix + "Calendar";
```

That doesn't work. If you need a calendar for multiple buttons add multiple calendars.

Comment: Ok, I have three ImageButton elements, each of them with a separate onClick event function that performs the same actions but creates different calendars with different IDs. Have I got it right?

Comment: @user3523583: all buttons could use the same click evnt handler but you need three calendars if you want to have three ID's. You could also use a single calendar but then i don't understand why you assign the ID in the button-click habdler. You can't do that in the event handler since that's far too late in the page's lifecycle.